# Can jinja2 templates access (and modify) global python script variables?

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to create a certain text file structure using python and jinja2. (not HTML). The files are static, and built of several segments, each segment is created by a different jinja template.

Each of these segments that come in random order must be numbered sequentially.

In principle:

```
Segment A  (no 1)
---
My Segment B (no 2)
---
Another Segment C (no 3)
```

I keep track of the current number using a variable in python.

I can of course transfer this variable to each template, like this.

```py
outfile=[]   # array for output
# get some objects...
for i in range(1,5):   # example to test
    t=myTemplate.render(nr=i, mystring=f"This is template nr {i}")
    outfile.append(t)
```

For clarity and simplicity, I would like to avoid having to transfer the global/s (there may be more) to every template render call.

Is it Jinja2 global namespaces I need to look for ?

Comment: For clarity, you **shouldn't** avoid transferring the globals every template render call.

Comment: but, check this should you really want to: `https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#the-global-namespace`

Comment: @matszwecja, understood. Can you give a small example of setting / getting varables with the global namespace ? I will accept that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify Jinja2 environment to define global variables that can be later accessed by any template within that environment like so:
(Example made with Flask app - other runtimes might mean different way of accessing the env)

```
app.jinja_env.globals['varName'] = 'variableValue'
```

this lets you access the variable just like it would be passed into `render_template`

```
return render_template("template.html", varName = 'variableValue')
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you modify your example to show use of globals *inside* the template ?

Comment: It is no different than usual usage of explicitly defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer because comments don't allow formatting.

The following ended doing the job.

My template:

```
; ------- text object ---------
TESTER: {{tester}}  # as explained by  matszwecja #
```

My script:

```py
import jinja2
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./templates")

templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader, newline_sequence='\r\n')

templateEnv.globals['tester'] = '12345'   # test for global stuff

Tobj_text=templateEnv.get_template('obj_text')

t=Tobj_text.render()

print (t)
```